# Hibernate gives me an error because an object references an unsaved transient instance - but I want it to remain unsaved in the DB

Tags: java, hibernate

I get the following error from Hibernate:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.avtain.primavera.data.Project
```

Within the project class, I have the following property:

```
@Transient
private Map<String,Task> taskIndex = new HashMap<String,Task>();
```

This map is just meant to act as a useful index, it doesn't have any data which isn't already in an `ArrayList` also containing the same data. I keep `taskIndex` updated with the following methods:

```
public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    taskIndex.clear();
    for(Task task : tasks)
        addTask(task);
}

public void addTask(Task task) {
    this.tasks.add(task);
    taskIndex.put(task.getTaskId(), task);
}
```

As you can see, there's no reason `taskIndex` should be saved in the database, and it should be updated once Hibernate builds a Project object simply by using my setter methods. I'm not sure why Hibernate is giving me this error.

Edit: Here is the list that actually should be persisted:

```
@OneToMany
List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
```

Comment: It may happen for another reason : you store tasks in your ArrayList. But are theses tasks persisted before ?

Comment: Well.. They should be. I may be doing something incorrectly, but I do have a list of tasks that should be persisted. Let me edit the question to show those.

Comment: I saw your edit. But with what param do you call addTask or setTasks ? Are you doing something like `Task myTask=new Task(......); myProject.addTask(myTask);` ? If so, myTask is not persisted when you call the addTask, and myTask is transient.

Comment: @ValBonn Sorry for my ignorance. How do I get something added this way to be persisted?

Comment: There are several ways. Either you can persist each Task you create before trying to persist the Project. Or you can do it in a cascade mode (saving a project will also save the tasks) : to do this way, you have to modify the @OneToMany annotation : `@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}) List<Task> tasks` (I am not 100% sure of the syntax - and you can look in the javadoc, there are several CascadeTypes)

Comment: @ValBonn This helped me a lot. Could you put this into an answer?

Comment: Too late, lametaweb answered before me ^^

Comment: @ValBonn Well you can still answer if you like

Comment: @ValBonn Well answer is more complete than mine. I didn't mention the posibility of persisting the Tasks by yourself without using cascade. Depending of the model semantic you should avoid cascade or not.

Comment: @lametaweb answer is perfect. No need to add something. EDIT : after reading his comment, he can edit his answer to write a word for the "without cascase" mode ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA Transient annotation has nothing to do with transient Hibernate entity concept. The latter is equivalent to the unmanaged entity concept in JPA. So the error is saying to you that in your Project entity bean there is another bean which has not been persisted before the flush happened. Probably you will have to add a cascade attribute to one of your Project entity bean attribute (not annotated Transient). I saw now the edit, so add:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.